# Using onTouch how to handle Swiping and Tapping both in Android Layout

Tags: android-layout, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

In the below code snippet (only the listener portion), i want to use the Single Tap only for Tapping the capture and Swiping if you are swiping.

In `onTouch()` if I return **false** then it gives me the Single Tapping feature and if I return **true** then I can handle the swipe feature using both `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

In Case of Tapping If I am trying to handle using both the action it's not happening, only through `ACTION_DOWN` it's getting.

Please help me out for the same.

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   
                x1 = e.getX();
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = e.getX();                  
                break;
        }      
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"touch",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
        return false;
    }
});
```